# Specifying docker network multiple times with traefik

Tags: docker, traefik, docker-network

I've seen many traefik examples specifying the docker network, and then respecifying it in traefik's static/dynamic config as well as in service containers.

`docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
networks:
  traefik:
    name: traefik

services:

  traefik:
    image: traefik
    # ...
    networks:
      - traefik
    command:
     - --providers.docker.network=traefik         # <--- necessary?

  whoami:
    image: traefik/whoami
    # ...
    networks:
      - traefik
    labels:
      traefik.docker.network: traefik             # <--- necessary?
```

For me it works without those commented lines.

Are they necessary? Why do those settings exist?